how to install netcdf c++ on linux?
Using popos, I was able to install netcdf and hdf5, but the C++ code I was building is complaining about:
#include <netcdfcpp.h>

and I cannot find that anywhere using find or locate.
I downloaded the source code: netcdf-cxx4-4.3.1
When I try to build, it complains about not finding <hdf5.h>
which is in /usr/include/hdf5/serial
Clearly the cmake for netcdf c++ binding doesn't find it.
I am trying to figure out how to add an include path to netcdf. It isn't an executable, so I can't just find the target of add_executable and set target_include_directory for that executable.
What I cannot believe is that a cmake build cannot find out that I have hdf5 installed and figure out the include. So rather than hacking it in, I am hoping there is a way to configure the package to realize the folder where it is.

"When I try to build, it complains about not finding <hdf5.h>" - Do not describe the error message. Instead, add to the question post exactly as it is, including the part which reference the compiled source file. Also, during the configuration CMake should print message(s) about finding hdf5. Have you checked that messages? Please, add them to the question post.

To resolve the issue with the C++ code not finding <netcdfcpp.h> and <hdf5.h>, you need to ensure that CMake is correctly configured to find both the NetCDF C++ bindings and the HDF5 library. Since you've already installed NetCDF and HDF5, the challenge is to make CMake aware of their locations.
For the NetCDF C++ bindings, ensure that the netCDFCxxConfig.cmake file is correctly located and that CMake can find it. This file is crucial for CMake to understand how to use the NetCDF C++ bindings in your project. If CMake cannot find this file, you might need to manually specify the path to the NetCDF C++ bindings using the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable. This can be done by appending the path to the installed NetCDF C++ bindings to the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH list variable in your CMake file:
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/path/to/installed/netcdf-cxx4")

Then, use find_package to locate the NetCDF C++ bindings:
find_package(netCDFCxx REQUIRED)

For the HDF5 library, since it's installed in /usr/include/hdf5/serial, you need to ensure that CMake is aware of this location. This can be done by setting the HDF5_ROOT variable to the root directory of the HDF5 installation before calling find_package(HDF5) in your CMakeLists.txt file:
set(HDF5_ROOT "/usr")
find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED)

This tells CMake where to look for the HDF5 library. After setting HDF5_ROOT, you can link against the HDF5 library in your target:
target_link_libraries(your_target_name PRIVATE HDF5::HDF5)

Remember to replace your_target_name with the actual name of your target.
By correctly setting up the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH for NetCDF C++ bindings and specifying the HDF5_ROOT for HDF5, CMake should be able to find both libraries and their include directories, resolving the issue with the missing headers.

Sorry, I don't understand. The only error at the moment is hdf5.h
I added:
set(HDF5_ROOT "/usr")
find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED)
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:36 (find_package):
Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses _ROOT variables.
Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
CMake variable HDF5_ROOT is set to:
/usr

For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable...

did you try adding
cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)
to your CmakeLists.txt file before the find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED) command ?

because, when a project specifies (with cmake_minimum_required) that it is written for CMake 3.11 (or older), CMake doesn't set policy CMP0074.
